# R: Could someone teach me how to change the x-axis sequence?

Tags: r

[image]

How do I show the x-axis label from 2010 to 2019?
Currently, it only shows 2010.0, 2012.5, 2015.0, 2017.5

Here are my codes:

```
ggplot(data=combineboth,aes(x=Year,y=`Percentage Change`,fill=Town))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge')+   
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                  breaks = c("Serangoon", "Bukit_Timah"),
                  values = c("Serangoon"="green", "Bukit_Timah"="blue")) +
  ggtitle("Percentage Change in HDB Resale Prices")+ xlab("Year")+ ylab("Percent (%)")+
  theme(
     plot.title = element_text(color="red",size=7, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5),
     axis.title.x = element_text(color="red", size=8, face="bold"),
     axis.title.y = element_text(color="red", size=8, face="bold"),
     axis.text=element_text(size=5)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to get nice date breaks is by converting year to a factor. Using some random data try this:

And if you want every year to show up then remove `scale_x_discrete`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(year = 2010:2020, y = runif(11))

ggplot(d, aes(factor(year), y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(2010, 2020, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>